# Do I have an accurate understanding of callback functions?

Tags: javascript

I've been a Javascript tinkerer for quite some time and recently I have been trying to have a real good understanding of the code I write. I want to get really good at writing Javascript. One of the things that's confused me a little bit was the usage of callback functions. I've just avoided using callbacks up until now. Right now, I'd like to know if my understanding of how a basic callback works is accurate and also if my understanding of parameters and arguments is accurate and finally, what the purpose is of using the callback in this scenario. Is there a benefit to using the callback function I've created below? If not, when are callback functions most beneficial? **I realize what I've written below is quite lengthy so for the TLDR people:** Am I right in thinking It's as if I created the function "theCallback" within "myFunction"? If so, what is the benefit in the scenario below? Why not just call a function? why must the function being called be an argument in the "myFunction" function?
If the scenario below doesn't make it necessary for using a callback, when is it necessary and what are the benefits? Thanks.

Here's how I see the code below: I've created a factory function "myFunction" with two parameters "x" and "callback" and parameters are pretty much variables that will be stored with arguments when the function is called. I also created another factory function "theCallback" with two parameters "x" and "theValue". Now since these are factory functions, regardless of them being underneath a function call to "myFunction", they will be hoisted above the function call so there are no problems. Had I created a function expression with a variable, they would not be hoisted. So now my call to "myFunction" has two arguments that the parameters in it will be defined as, "3" and "theCallback". The "theCallback" argument is a function. This function has the two parameters "x" and "theValue". When "myFunction" is called, "x" is stored with the argument "3" and "callback" is stored with the function "theCallback" and then the code within "myFunction" is executed which is simply a variable declared and assigned a value of a string that contains the text "for the callback" and the callback variable (I'm viewing as a variable), which was a parameter that is now an argument which is "theCallback" function I created which also contains parameters itself, is called, and given arguments for it's code to execute. In this case, the code it will execute calls the built in alert function (or method of the window object?) and gives the alert function a string argument, followed by the 
alert function called again with the argument of "x" which is stored with "3" and then again alert is called and given the argument of "theValue" which contains the string "for the callback". Now when "theCallback" function is passed as a second argument to "myFunction" and it's stored in "callback", It's as if I created the function "theCallback" within "myFunction" right? If so, what is the benefit in the scenario below? Why not just call a function, why must the function being called be an argument in the "myFunction" function?
If the scenario below doesn't make it necessary for using a callback, when is it necessary and what are the benefits?

```
myFunction(3, theCallback);

function myFunction(x, callback){
  var value = 'for the callback';    
  callback(x, value);    
}

function theCallback(x, theValue){
  alert('this is the callback function');
  alert(x);
  alert(theValue);  
}
```

Comment: it's long to explain. read this: http://sporto.github.io/blog/2012/12/09/callbacks-listeners-promises/

Comment: Wow, dude. Chill. I'm not that much of a __TLDR__ person, but that doesn't look easy to read.

Comment: You need to shorten your question a little, dear sir.

Comment: Repeating yourself less and using paragraphs would make this a lot easier to reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a benefit to using the callback function I've created below?

That's a little subjective. Using a callback is unnecessary there. Normally you would return data from one function and pass it to the other.

> when are callback functions most beneficial?

When you need to deal with the data after an event has fired, instead of immediately. e.g. when a button is clicked or an HTTP response has fired.

```
myButton.addEventListener("click", myCallbackFunction);
```

> I've created a factory function "myFunction"

No. That is just a function. [Factory functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) create class objects.

> they will be hoisted

Function *declarations* (as opposed to function expressions) are hoisted. This isn't relevant to callbacks though. A callback is basically a function passed as an argument, it doesn't matter how it was created.

> what are the benefits

The benefits are that you can have different things happen when the event fires depending on the circumstance.

Take the click event example above. Often you'll want clicking on different things to have different effects, not the one thing that `addEventListener` was hardcoded to make happen by the browser vendor.

Comment: So addEventListener is a function (method) that's built into Javascript and the second argument is a callback function that the addEventListener method will call much like in my example above of the function that's been passed the callback function as an argument and calls it?